# How do I replace part of a url without breaking the link?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following URL:

```
const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Los%20Angeles.json?access_token=${map_api_key}`;
```

I'm trying to follow a tutorial demonstration of error handling, but the tutorial uses a string URL with concatenation in its demonstration as it retains the API key in the URL, but since I'm posting it to github I had to hide the API key so I used a template literal in the URL. The problem I'm running into is I don't know how to replace `Los%20Angeles` in the URL with whatever address/city is in the geocode call.

```js
const geocode = (address, callback) => {
    const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Los%20Angeles.json?access_token=${map_api_key}&limit=1`;

    request({ url: url, json: true}, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            callback('Unable to connect to location services!', undefined);
        } else if (response.body.features.length === 0) {
            callback('Unable to find location. Try another search.', undefined);
        }
    });
}

// example function call
geocode('New York', (error, data) => {
    console.log('Error', error);
    console.log('Data', data);
});
```

Each variation I've tried breaks the link. For example `${address}.json?access_token=${map_api_key}` doesn't seem to work.

**Question:** Is there a way to accomplish this without breaking the link?

Comment: Sorry, I have the api key defined further up in the file as `const map_api_key = process.env.MAP_API_KEY;` and it works fine, but it's just that when I try to replace that city it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably should `encodeURI()` city name.

`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${encodeURI(address)}.json?access_token=${map_api_key}&limit=1`

Comment: This helped a little bit. I was able to get to the `if(error){ }`

Answer (score 0):

Better use the URL() constructor, it should encode strings properly:

```
const url = new URL(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${address}.json?access_token=${map_api_key}&limit=1`);
```